# Possibility of spoofing miners in Ethereum

Tags: security, devp2p, p2p, denial-of-service

Ethereum uses node IDs to identify nodes uniquely and to route traffic between nodes based on the node discovery protocol (https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/discv4.md) built on Kademlia-like DHTs.

1. What's stopping an adversary `M` from spoofing as a legitimate miner by deriving their own node ID from their own public key and taking part in the node discovery protocol, which would add `M`'s route also to the Kadmelia-like DHTs eventually?
2. Since the node ID is derived from the public key of a node, can't an adversary steal key pairs from a legitimate miner and spoof as one? Couldn't this lead to a DoS attack?

If these are in fact security issues, isn't there a mechanism to blacklist spoofing miners or cut their stake (In the case of Proof-of-Stake) when Eth2.0 is released?

Comment: Because one cannot spoof private keys, any security issue described here is not real.

Comment: 1) is about "deriving own node ID from own public key and taking part in the node discovery protocol, which would add M's route also to the Kadmelia-like DHTs eventually?". You don't spoof private keys.
2) "an adversary can steal key pairs from a legitimate miner and spoof as one", stealing and spoofing private keys is different. In 2) I am asking about stealing key pairs.
I don't mention anywhere about spoofing private keys.